# Computing NDVI with PyQGIS in PyCharm

Tags: pyqgis, ndvi, pycharm

I'm actually new to Python and QGIS. I'm using PyCharm as my code editor.
I'm trying to load a raster layer in the following below:

```
import os
import qgis.core
from osgeo import gdal,gdal_array
from qgis.utils import iface

os.chdir ("C:/Users/User/Desktop/Ih_HowtoCalculateVegetationIndexNDVIfromSentinel2withPyQGIS/Ih_HowtoCalculateVegetationIndexNDVIfromSentinel2withPyQGIS/Sentinel2Clip")
print(os.listdir(os.getcwd()))
sni
SWIR = iface.addRasterLayer('clip_RT_S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MTI__20160506T214824_A004555_T18LTM_B11.tif','SWIR')
NIR = iface.addRasterLayer('clip_RT_S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MTI__20160506T214824_A004555_T18LTM_B08.tif','NIR')
```

but I'm getting the following an attribute error in the code.

```
C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\python3.exe C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/unit/proj.py

  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/unit/proj.py", line 9, in <module>
    SWIR = iface.addRasterLayer('clip_RT_S2A_OPER_MSI_L1C_TL_MTI__20160506T214824_A004555_T18LTM_B11.tif','SWIR')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addRasterLayer'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 0):

When you run your code within PyCharm, you are in a QGIS standalone application case. `iface` is never available in standalone QGIS application, only within a running QGIS.

If you do `from qgis.utils import iface` and then `print(iface)`, you get `None`. You are asking a method `addRasterLayer` on a `None` object (try running `None.addRasterLayer` ;) ), hence the error you mentioned

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addRasterLayer'

Look at recipes to use QGIS as standalone application.

Comment: Thanks so much Mr Thomas. As I said ealier I'm new to both QGIS and python hence I'm so confuse looking at the recipes. I don't really know where to start from. can you please help me out? Thanks.